# Redux state change does not rerender the component based on logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom, redux-toolkit

I have a React app (Vite) with Redux for global state management. I have a global state called `auth` of boolean in Redux store and it is updated through dispatcher when the user correctly signs up to the app or signs in to the app. I can see this state change is happening in the Redux dev tools. But the component `Home` is supposed to be rendered when the state of this auth is true. But it does not. I don't know how to go about debugging this. I have attached the relevant code snippets.

**main**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <ErrorBoundary>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Routes />
    </Provider>
  </ErrorBoundary>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Routes**

```
export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
        <Route path='/login' component={Signin} />
        <Route path='/register' component={Signup} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

**App**

```
export default function App() {
  return <PrivateRoute component={Home} />
}
```

**PrivateRoute**

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  const authenticated = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth.isLogged);

  return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) =>
          authenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to={'/login'} />
        }
      />
  );
}
```

**Signin**

```
const Signin = () => {
    const [state, handlers] = useSignin();

    return (
        <SigninUI {...state} {...handlers} />
    )
}

export default Signin;
```

**Signin handler**

```js
const useSignin = (): [SigninState, SigninHandlers] => {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

    const handleSubmit: SigninHandlers["handleSubmit"] = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        apis.signin(state.email, state.pwd)
            .then((data) => {
                setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, errorMsg: "", successMsg: data.data.message }));
                dispatch(authActions.login())
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, successMsg: "", errorMsg: e.data.message }));
            })
    }

    return [state, { handleEmailChange, handlePwdChange, handleSubmit }]
}
```

**useAppSelector, useAppDispatch**

```js
export const useAppDispatch = useDispatch.withTypes<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector = useSelector.withTypes<RootState>();
```

**store**

```js
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
  },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

**authReducer**

```js
const initialState: AuthState = {
  isLogged: false,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    login: (state) => {
      state.isLogged = true;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.isLogged = false;
    },
  },
});

export const authActions = authSlice.actions;
export const authReducer = authSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: You can log to the console to check if the is logged value actually changes.
export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  const authenticated = useAppSelector((state) => {
    console.log('Current authentication status:', state.auth.isLogged);
    return state.auth.isLogged;
  });

  console.log('Rendering PrivateRoute with authenticated:', authenticated);

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        authenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to={'/login'} />
      }
    />
  );
}

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything that navigates a user from `"/login"` or `"/register"` after a user successfully authenticates. You can add an imperative redirect to `"/"` after authenticating.

Example:

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const useSignin = (): [SigninState, SigninHandlers] => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const handleSubmit: SigninHandlers["handleSubmit"] = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    apis.signin(state.email, state.pwd)
      .then((data) => {
        setState((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          errorMsg: "",
          successMsg: data.data.message
        }));
        dispatch(authActions.login());
        history.replace("/"); // <-- redirect to home page
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        setState((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          successMsg: "",
          errorMsg: e.data.message
        }));
      });
  };

  return [state, { handleEmailChange, handlePwdChange, handleSubmit }]
};
```

Something else that may help is to use a more correct route protection implementation.

Example:

```
export default function PrivateRoute(props) {
  const authenticated = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth.isLogged);

  return authenticated ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />;
}
```

You may want to also create a protected route that does the inverse of this component to protect the login/register routes from authenticated users.

```
export default function AnonymousRoute(props) {
  const authenticated = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth.isLogged);

  return authenticated ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Route {...props} />;
}
```

Usage:

```
export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute path='/login' component={Signin} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/register' component={Signup} />
        <AnonymousRoute path='/' component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```